# Meaning of Finite-dimensional subspace of $C_0(\Omega,\mathbb R^N)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am reading a paper which has something to do with a finite-dimensional subspace of $C_0(\Omega,\mathbb R^N)$.

In this paper, it about to compute a value defined as 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_j\| A_j u\|_{\mathcal M(\Omega)}\tag 1
$$
for $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_N)$ with $\alpha_j\in (0,\infty)$ a constant, where $A_j$ is a first order linear differential operator and $u\in BV(\Omega)$. $\mathcal M$ denote the total variation of Radon measure. This definition is easy to understand.

Then, the author remarks that it could allow for spatially dependent parameters $\alpha$, but $\alpha$ need to lie in a finite-dimensional subspace of $C_0(\Omega,\mathbb R^N)$, and hence one could simply replace the sum in $(1)$ as a larger sum modeling integration over parameters with values in a finite-dimensional subspace of $C_0(\Omega,\mathbb R^N)$.

I kind of lost here. I think the remark wants to state that instead of $\alpha$ being a constant vector in $\mathbb R^N$, we could take $\alpha$ in $C_0(\Omega,\mathbb R^N)$, that is, each $\alpha_j\in C_0(\Omega)$ a function. Then we have to change $(1)$ to be

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \|\alpha_j(x) A_j u\|_{\mathcal M(\Omega)} \tag2
$$
and the term $\|\alpha_j(x) A_j u\|_{\mathcal M(\Omega)}$ is kind of a weighted Radon measure space, which is not trivial to study.

My question: what the "finite-dimensional subspace of $C_0(\Omega,\mathbb R^N)$" doing here? and why we could simply replace the sum in $(1)$ as a larger sum in $(2)$? I think in $(2)$ is not a larger sum, it is an integration in some sense and it is not trivial to study.

Finally, by "finite-dimensional subspace of $C_0(\Omega,\mathbb R^N)$", what is the formal definition here? Just a linear combination of finitely many continuous functions?